# KiCad clearance vs JLCPCB clearance

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, kicad

From [JLCPCB][1] it lists many type of clearances.

[image]

However in KiCad, it only lists one type of clearance, and I don't know what it is.

0.5mm is the highest value for clearance in JLCPCB and in KiCad it's 0.2mm by default. Should I just change it to 0.5mm for all type of clearances?

Comment: I _think_ those Kicad settings are for tracks. The minimums for tracks at JLCPCB are in the "Minimum trace width and spacing" section on that page, and they are below 0.2 mm. There seems to be more control over the other constraints in the next version of Kicad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ordered PCBs at JLCPCB with a KiCad design and I ran into exactly the same question.

As @Mat has already pointed out, the clearance of the net classes are copper clearances. Unfortunately you cannot specify more sophisticated clearances in KiCad 5.

If your PCB is very basic and you only uses large parts, I'd probably just have a quick look and check things manually by eye. However, if you want to make a genuine DRC I suggest you try out the KiCad Nightly development builds since KiCad 6 is not yet released.

I found this of KiCad 6 preview which shows the new "Constraints" pane (you have to scroll down a bit) that has a lot more detailed options for PCB restrictions:
https://techexplorations.com/blog/kicad/kicad-6-review-new-and-improved-features/